# How to select a specific build agent from Azure pipelines to run your build on?

Tags: azure, deployment, yaml, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to come up with a way to allow an easy selection of a given agent within the build pipeline just for debugging purposes. So far I have the below snippet. Both work without the if snippets wrapped around but I was trying to do one or the other based on either params being set or inturn variables being set so that if it was in debug mode it would select and agent and if it wasn't then it would just use the pool to select an agent to run the builds against. So far no luck though.

```
variables:
  debugMode: 'false'

parameters:
- name: poolOption
  type: string
  default: 'ZupaDeploymentPool'
- name: debugMode
  type: string
  default: 'true'
- name: debugMachine
  type: string
  default: 'ZUPBUILD03'

trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
    - master
  paths:
    exclude:
    - README.md

${{ if ne($(debugMode), 'false') }}:
  pool: ${{ parameters.poolOption }} 

${{ if ne($(debugMode), 'true') }}:
  pool:
    name: ${{ parameters.poolOption }}
    demands: 
    - Agent.Name -equals ${{ parameters.debugMachine }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your YAML sample and made some modifications. You could try to set the "Expressions" under a stage and check if it could work as expected.

Here is an example, you could refer to it.

```
trigger:
- master


parameters:
- name: poolOption
  type: string
  default: 'Windows-latest'

- name: debugMode
  type: string
  default: false
  values:
    - true
    - false


- name: debugMachine
  type: string
  default: 'ubuntu-16.04'

stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: testjob
    pool:
     ${{ if eq(parameters.debugmode, 'true') }}:
      vmImage: ${{ parameters.poolOption }}
      
     ${{ if eq(parameters.debugmode, 'false') }}:
      vmImage: ${{ parameters.debugMachine }}


    steps:
      - script : "echo Hello, world!"
```

Note: I am using Microsoft-hosted agents, so I am using the `vmImage` field.

You can [specify specific self-hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#pool) (`name` field) according to your needs.

Comment: This looks promising I will have a look when I get up in the morning. Thanks for having a look into this. Will get back to you if I cant get it working but the suggestion is very clear thanks.

Comment: If you have any updates, feel free to let me know. I will continue to help you.

Comment: Much appreciated the solution above didnt work but I have something that does and I'm going to post it in the answers section of this thread. But without your suggestion, I wouldn't have found this solution so thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

So after having a quick chat with kevin-lu-msft above lead me to this solution for handling selecting a specific agent in the pool.

```yaml
parameters:
- name: debugMachine
  displayName: 'Run on selected agent:'
  type: string
  default: 'Auto Select From Pool'
  values:
  - 'Auto Select From Pool'
  - 'MACHINE01'
  - 'MACHINE02'
  - 'MACHINE03'
  - 'MACHINE04'
  - 'MACHINE05'

jobs:
-job: build

  # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # This is the pool selection section if a specific debug machine is passed in via the params 
  # It will select that specific one to run the build on. unfortunately azure doesnt let you pass 
  # vars or params to the process string in the demands which would have made this alot cleaner.
  pool:
    name: 'YOUAGENTSPOOLNAME'
    ${{ if ne(parameters.debugMachine, 'Auto Select From Pool') }}:
      ${{ if eq(parameters.debugMachine, 'MACHINE01') }}:
        demands:
        - Agent.Name -equals MACHINE01
      ${{ if eq(parameters.debugMachine, 'MACHINE02') }}:
        demands:
        - Agent.Name -equals MACHINE02
      ${{ if eq(parameters.debugMachine, 'MACHINE03') }}:
        demands:
        - Agent.Name -equals MACHINE03
      ${{ if eq(parameters.debugMachine, 'MACHINE04') }}:
        demands:
        - Agent.Name -equals MACHINE04
      ${{ if eq(parameters.debugMachine, 'MACHINE05') }}:
        demands:
        - Agent.Name -equals MACHINE05

  steps:
    - script: "echo finally it works"
```

Comment: Hi Chris, is it possible for the pipeline to determine which agent is available in the pool? Say I have an agent pool with two agents installed. If one my pipelines is using agent1 to run the build and another pipeline has been triggered, is there a way to configure it in such a way that if it sees that agent1 is being used then it will use agent2 instead, and vice-versa?